# CMake/CPack - Generate Debian Package Maintainer Scripts (postrm specifically)

Tags: cmake, package, deb, cpack

My build "superbuilds" other projects, all of which may change at any time. It is far too tedious to manually create the postrm script every time we want to build...

Is there a way to generate the postrm script when building a Debian package with CMake/CPack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the common answer is to use debhelpers, with something like [cmake-debhelper](https://github.com/sebknzl/cmake-debhelper), *although I have not tried this*.

I accomplished this by creating two custom targets, one that executes `make`, and another which depends on the previous `make` target and runs a python script to generate the maintainer scripts followed by `capck`.